# Simulate CDF of sum of i.i.d. F distributions

Tags: distributions, random-variable, simulation, f-distribution

I have trouble on simulating the CDF of a random variable Y, where $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{12} X_i$, and $X_i$ are i.i.d. F-distribution.

I am doing this in MATLAB, the problem is that small instance of Y hardly occurs. I don't think I can use Importance Sampling since I don't know the density function of Y(I doubt there is an analytic formula). Central Limit Theorem won't work since 12 isn't very large.

What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what an "F-distribution" is?  Are you referring to the [central F distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution) or just to some generic distribution? (Your remark about not knowing the density of $Y$ suggests the latter.)

Comment: $X_i = \frac{U_1/d_1}{U_2/d_2}$, where $U_1$ and $U_2$ are independent Chi-Square distributions with degree of freedom $d_1$and$d_2$ respectively.

Comment: Then you *do* know the density and there *is* a simple closed formula for it: please visit the link I gave you.

Comment: @whuber: do you mean there is a density for the $F$ distribution or for the sum? An eleven dimension convolution seems daunting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not certain what you mean by "simulating the cdf of Y". From a simulated sample of $Y$'s you can certainly plot the empirical cdf. For instance,

```
y=apply(matrix(rf(12*1e5,df1=3,df2=7),ncol=12),1,sum)
plot(ecdf(y))
```

returns an empirical cdf in R. The precision of this approximation is provided by the Binomial nature of the empirical cdf, namely$$N\hat{F}(x)\sim\mathcal{B}(N,F(x))$$To show this precision I plotted 100 independent realisations of the above code on the same graph: the variability is of the order of the thickness of the lines used to draw the cdf. [image]

> The issue of not getting samples of $Y$ close to zero is an altogether
>   different question that you should rephrase with more details.

However, one generic remark about the density of $Y$ being unavailable for basic importance sampling is that one can use [Monte Carlo (de)marginalisation](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00311793/document) to get around the issue. Given that the density of $(X_1,\ldots,X_{12})$ is available as $$\prod_{i=1}^{12} \mathfrak{f}(x_i|\nu_1,\nu_2)$$it suffices to choose an importance function (density) on $(X_1,\ldots,X_{12})$ that produces small values of $(X_1,\ldots,X_{12})$, 
$$\prod_{i=1}^{12} \mathfrak{g}(x_i)$$
and to use the importance ratio
$$\prod_{i=1}^{12} \mathfrak{f}(x_i|\nu_1,\nu_2)/\mathfrak{g}(x_i)$$

Comment: That what I did. But is there a way to check how accurate is the empirical distribution function. I don't have any analytic result to compare with. Neither can I artificially get samples near 0 (like the trick in importance sampling). So I am not very confident about the empirical distribution function.

Comment: CQNKZX, by questioning this solution, you are suggesting either R's implementation of `rf` may be erroneous or that R does not add correctly.  Let's assume you are willing to trust its addition.  To verify the result, then, all you have to do is check that `rf` generates variates independently and according to the specified F distribution.  Since you *do* know the density for that, the distribution check is straightforward to do: you may use QQ plots, compare a histogram to the density, and even run goodness of fit tests. There are many ways to check independence, too.

Comment: The Monte Carlo marginalization you mentioned sounds very interesting, could you give me a reference about it, a book or paper will be great. Thank you!

Comment: We mention the notion of de-marginalisation in our book with George Casella, [Monte Carlo Statistical Methods](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/wp-admin/link.php?action=edit&link_id=26).

Comment: @Xi'an Your answer is excellent! I just learnt how to accept your answer, thank you!

Comment: @whuber Good point. Maybe I thought too much about the accuracy issue. I think my real question is about sampling rare events. Thank you!